# ObservableCollection doesn't update ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

My ObservableCollection list doesn't update view. I use MVVM Light

This is my VM

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase{
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }

private void GetData()
{
    //getting data here

    Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();

    foreach (var item in myData)
    {
        Products.Add(item);
    }
}}
```

XAML:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"><FlowDocumentReader BorderBrush = "Black" BorderThickness="2">
<FlowDocument>
    <BlockUIContainer>
        <ListView BorderThickness = "2" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "Lp." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrdinalNumber}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "Quantity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "NetPrice" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NetPrice}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "GrossPrice" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GrossPrice}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "TotalCost" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TotalCost}" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
```

For me it looks fine. I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem with ObservableCollection, but with setting a Products property.

```
Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
```

You set it in the GetData method, but you never notify the view about it, so it's not bound to your ObservableCollection.
You can instead set a property in a constructor, or use INotifyPropertyChanged also on the property.

Comment: ufff, I see now. I sit doing this project all day. I need fresh air

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already inherited from ViewModelBase, therefore you won't need to do this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Instead, you can just do this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase{
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }

private void GetData()
{
    //getting data here

    Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();

    foreach (var item in myData)
    {
        Products.Add(item);
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Products)); // you are missing this
}}
```